# Enable/Disable buttons in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have function like this where I'm enabling or disabling buttons.

```
  var manageButtons = function(status) {
      if(status === 'inactive') {
          $("input[type='submit'], button").addClass('inactive').attr('disabled', true);
      }
      else {
          $("input[type='submit'], button").removeClass('inactive').removeAttr('disabled');
      }     
  };
```

Instead of passing the status as 'inactive' or 'active', I want to pass boolean values like true & false.

I want to do something like manageButtons(true) or manageButtons(false) instead of manageButtons('active') or manageButtons('inactive'). How can I do that?? Any help on this please?? Or do you suggest any better approach??

Comment: Replace the `status === 'inactive'` with something like `status == false`?

Comment: Well simply pass `true` or `false` to this function rather than passing `'active'` or `'inactive'`

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
var manageButtons = function(status) {
    $("input[type='submit'], button").prop('disabled', status);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**if you are interrested to add and remove class inactive**

```
var manageButtons = function(status) {
          if(!status) {
              $("input[type='submit'], button").addClass('inactive').prop('disabled', true);
          }
          else {
             $("input[type='submit'],button").removeClass('inactive').prop('disabled',false);
          }   

      };
```

**if you are not interested to add and remove class then by only single line**

```
 var manageButtons = function(status) {
        $("input[type='submit'], button").prop('disabled', status);
    };
```

**at call time**

```
manageButtons(0);
manageButtons(1);
```